REG value or powershell to fix "SWAP BACK to a default language when launch another program and/or alt+Tab"
Long time ago I noticed that feature : It was either when one launces a new program that is not opened yet or when you alt+tab windows between programs - the typing language would always swap back to default UI language. Very neat feature most of the time.
But that week I was working on something in the same language (fr) and by a chance I found either a registry key or a powershell line that changed that feature to stay on the already changed language state. It was a long day I forgot a note how to change it back to 'auto defeault typing lng'.
Most people don't even notice that feature and never bother to find out where it store in registry. And could find that info once again. So I hope someone in here might know what I'm talking about.
Did search web and old notes in 3 years no result.
